# difference between spring web scopes and servlet scopes

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, scopes

Spring MVC has two web based scopes, exclusively for the Servlet technology, `request` and `session`.

Are these two scopes the same as `Servlet` scopes that is defined as per the Java Servlet Technology documentation?

What does the Servlet's `Web Context` scope map to in Spring MVC?

Comment: 1. yes. 2. application. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-other

Comment: @JBNizet Kindly mention this as answer. Will mark it as an answer.